# Please what can i do to resolve this?

Tags: php

```
 $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email = $dbvars['email'] , 
           hash = $dbvars['hash']");
```

here is the error;

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
> expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or
> number (T_NUM_STRING) in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mylifepro\tero_biz\lib\Job.php on line 9

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Strings in SQL queries need to be surrounded by quotes. Try

```php
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email = '$dbvars['email']', 
           hash = '$dbvars['hash']'");
```